# application server works

Tags: jakarta-ee, ear, application-server

An ear file has many wars and jars in it. How does the application server knows which war file to invoke after deployment of .ear in it?

Comment: The app server doesn't invoke any war file. It deploys them. And it deploys them because they're in the ear file. I don't get your question.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you wanted to ask: how particular wars (meaning web applications) are triggered? If so, the answer is: an EAR application descriptor (`application.xml`) defines **context root** for each WAR it contains. The context root is the URL portion occurring immediately after host and port, for example:

```
<module>
  <web>
    <web-uri>some.war</web-uri>
    <context-root>/somepath</context-root>
  </web>
</module>
```

Every URL of the form `http://host:port/somepath/*` is directed by the HTTP server component of a Java EE application server to the application contained in `some.war`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the correct answer of MaDa: if the context root is not explicitly specified in either `application.xml` or a proprietary deployment descriptor, then the name of the war file (minus the extension) will be taken as the context root.

For instance, given a `some.war` inside a `myapp.ear`, and a server listening on HTTP port 8080, you can reach your web module via: `http://localhost:8080/some/`